# VB.net Passing parameter to function with a stored procedure

Tags: sql, vb.net, function

I am trying to call a function that populate a datatable, but it is not working and I am lost. I am getting a function error. Function doesn't return a value on all code paths. Here's is my code please help thank you.

```
Protected Sub Search_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Search.Click
        strPartNumber = txtPartNumber.Text

            Dim CT As DataTable = Me.GetCompanyInfo(strPartNumber, "None")
            dvCommon.DataSource = CT
            dvCommon.DataBind()
    End Sub

Private Function GetCompanyInfo(ByRef PartNumber As String, ByRef Version As String) As DataTable
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DefaultConnection").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("spCommonInfo")
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartNumber", PartNumber)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Version", Version)
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Dim CT As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(CT)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
```

Comment: `I am getting a function error.`  Are you going to keep that error a secret?  Your CT isn't getting returned.  It just gets filled and then dies.

Comment: @LarsTech Please Tell me how to return it.

Comment: You need `Return CT` at the bottom of your function.  Move the `Dim CT As New DataTable` line above your `Using con...` line.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see your method `GetCompanyInfo` returns a datatable as `As DataTable` but no where in code you are returning one.

You should return the DataTable you have filled

```
Return CT
```

Your function code should be

```
Private Function GetCompanyInfo(ByRef PartNumber As String, ByRef Version As String) As DataTable
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DefaultConnection").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Dim CT As New DataTable()
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("spCommonInfo")
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartNumber", PartNumber)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Version", Version)
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)                    
                    sda.Fill(CT)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
     Return CT
    End Function
```